# C# about sending simulated keyboard events to another APP

Tags: c#, winapi

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            SetForegroundWindow(wndHandle);
            SendKeys.SendWait("123");
    }
```

I use WIN32 API ,use the Sendkey to achieve my target,but using the Sendkey has a disadvantage that "I have to SetForegroundWindow() before I use sendkey",it doesn't match my wish.

I want to click a button in the GUI which C# created, and then it will simulate the keyboard event to another app, and most important of all, I wish I don't have to set the window of app  to be the ground window.

Does anyone have idea how to do it? I appreciate  your help very much.

Does the target application must be currently active?

Comment: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

Comment: Why do you feel the need to fake input? Why did you reject automation, or are you not aware of automation?

Comment: Sorry I am a freshman to C#, and I totally don't have any idea to UI Automation, I will google for this. Thank you a lot.